# Is Jesus truly God?

Tags: life-of-jesus, biblical-basis

I was looking for an answer that I could link someone to, but it looks like this question has not been asked yet. I am looking for an answer that is as direct and conclusive as possible.

Does or does not the Bible say that Jesus is God?